# Mongoose still sends password field with select: false

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

I am not sure where I am going wrong with this.  I have my UserSchema that has select: false for the password field.  It only sends the password field when I use .create() on the User model.

User Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an email address'],
        unique: [true, 'This email is already in use'],
        validate: {
            validator: checkEmail,
            message: 'Not a valid e-mail'
        }
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a username'],
        unique: [true, 'That username has been taken.']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a password'],
        select: false
    }
});

function checkEmail() {
    return validator.isEmail(this.email);
}

module.exports = new mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

My controller

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const asyncHandler = require('../middleware/async');

//@desc     Register a new user
//@path     POST /api/v1/auth/register
//@auth     Public
exports.registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.create(req.body);
    
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: user
    });
});

//@desc     Login a new user
//@path     POST /api/v1/auth/login
//@auth     Public
exports.loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Path for logging in'
    });
});
```

What can I do to not send the password field back with the user data?

Answer (score 3):

Had this same issue, this is old but just incase someone with same issue arrives here in future time.

I realised that the {select:false} only seems to work when you use find queries in mongoose.

I also tried using `delete user.password` which didn't work cause I had to convert the user response to javascript object, but when converted like so `const new_user = user.toObject() delete new_user["password"` 
I realised that the nested object I had in the User schema weren't returned with the new_user.

to cut story short the work around I did was use the spread operator to spread out user, and then set password to undefined

```
user: {...user._doc, password: undefined},
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select what to return:

```
if (newUser) {
  res.status(201).send({
    // do this to prevent returning password hash:
    name: newUser.name,
    email: newUser.email,
  });
}
```

Comment: This is not a practical solution for all the scenarios, when ever you query from the user model you have to filter out the password field. Really????